# Unable to show hide drop-down on modal form

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to show/hide dropdown on my modal form, but some how its not working 
attaching my html code.
Code got 1 Drop-box with 3 values and I want to show/hide another drop-box based on the input.
--HTML--

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">           
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Contact Type: </label>
      <select id="ownership" data-placeholder="Select Ownership"  class="required select-full"  tabindex="2"  name="st">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="1">VIP</option>
        <option value="2">Collector</option>
        <option value="3">Client</option>

      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="vip" >

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Sold To: <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
        <select data-placeholder="USD" class="required select-full" id="soldto1" name="soldto1">
          <option value=""></option>
              </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="coll" >

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Sold To: <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
        <select data-placeholder="USD" class="required select-full" id="soldto2" name="soldto2">
          <option value=""></option>
           </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="clil" >

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Sold To: <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
        <select data-placeholder="USD" class="required select-full" id="soldto3" name="soldto3">
          <option value=""></option>
               </select>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

--jQuery--

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vip').hide();
    $('#coll').hide();
    $('#clil').hide();
    $('#ownership').change(function() {

      if ($('#ownership option:selected').text() == 'VIP') {
        $('#vip').show();
        $('#coll').hide();
        $('#clil').hide();

      }
      if ($('#ownership option:selected').text() == 'Collector') {
        $('#vip').hide();
        $('#coll').show();
        $('#clil').hide();
      } if ($('#ownership option:selected').text() == 'Client') {
        $('#vip').hide();
        $('#coll').hide();
        $('#clil').show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Ur code seems working fine to me..http://jsfiddle.net/k6dttyqg/

Comment: @Outlooker , Yup code seems to be running on plain html , but when i use this code on my modal it does nothing.

Comment: do u have any console errors

Comment: I really can't comment about it,until i get a clear idea about it mate